# Wait all threads finish in Service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a `Service` where I run a task inside a Thread. I call this `Service` many times and obviously it creates the corresponding number of Threads.

How am I going to know when no one `Thread` is running so I can call `stopSelf()` ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is make your service subclass [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).  This is a special kind of Service that will perform work in a background thread, and automatically stop the service when there is no more work to perform.  There is a single thread per Service that you declare in your manifest.  All you do is determine what sort of work you want to perform by implementing its [onHandleIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)), which is automatically run in that background thread for each Intent delivered to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the running threads in an array. When each thread completes it should remove itself from the array and call a method that checks if there are any running threads. That method just checks if the list of running threads is empty, and if so, calls `stopSelf()`.

Or use `IntentService` if this suits your needs.